# Unknown mass case updates?

Tags: case, update, scheduled-job, case-object

I have had a few instances in the past couple months where my running user is doing mass updates to cases which changes the status to Closed.  I have no idea what's causing it or where to even being to troubleshoot.  I figured I could look at job history to see if anything lines up and I do see a couple different jobs being ran during the time of the latest update, but no actual batches were processed.  Any ideas on how to go about troubleshooting?

Comment: Does the user have Manage Cases permission? They'd have the ability to mass close cases directly in the UI without any specific logging.

Comment: Time-Dependent Actions (Workflow Rules or Process Builder) would be the second place I'd look.

Comment: @DavidReed - I've checked both of those and don't see anything that would time dependant to close.  I'm assuming I can see the time dependant workflows via the Paused and Waiting Interviews within Flows? In which case, nothing is pending from cases

Comment: @sfdcfox - yeah, the user is me and I'm the primary admin of the org.  I'm not positive, but I have a pretty good guess this started happening when I installed a Managed Package through the AppExchange - The GotoWebinar Integration.  I've reached out to their developers and they state nothing in their code would be updating cases, but conveniently enough, it happens when a Future batch is ran.